# What is the difference in TMSCHEMA vs MDSCHEMA in DMV of Power BI models

Tags: powerbi, daxstudio, dmv, tabular-editor

For example, what is the difference between in those 2 when querying DMV?

```
select * from $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES

select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

When those queries are going to return different results?

Comment: The technically correct answer is "always", because they have different schemas. `MD` = Multidimensional, `TM` = Tabular Model. Tabular model is largely compatible with multidimensional views and MDX queries, so you can consider the `MD` views a feature for backwards compatibility. As PowerBI always uses SSAS in tabular mode, there is largely no reason to use them.

Answer (score 0):

The TM tables are generally the better ones to use for Tabular models, though you can use either for Tabular. The columns and sometimes the rows are different though. For example measures, I get an extra row on the MD query for a hidden measure:
[image: MDSCHEMA_MEASURES]

You can see the columns for each using these links.
[`MDSCHEMA_MEASURES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas/5dcec425-fc2e-4476-8033-6ce282d69afd)
[`TMSCHEMA_MEASURES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas-t/ab331e04-78f7-49f0-861f-3f155b8b4c5b)

I do a lot with the TM DMV tables, and I think the only MD table I ever use is `MDSchema_Dimensions` to get row counts.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  [CATALOG_NAME] as [Database],
  DIMENSION_CAPTION AS [Table],
  FORMAT(DIMENSION_CARDINALITY,'###,###,###') AS [RowCount]
FROM $system.MDSchema_Dimensions
WHERE DIMENSION_CAPTION <> 'Measures'  --table name
AND CUBE_NAME = 'Model'
ORDER BY DIMENSION_CARDINALITY DESC  --RowCount
```

You can also get row counts from `DISCOVER_STORAGE_TABLES`, but because you can't write full SQL (eg. `GROUP BY`) when using DMVs, you have to jump through hoops after the query to get the right answer.